# How can a user delete themselves in an ASP.NET Core 2 app using ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm exploring ASP.NET Identity with ASP.NET Core 2.0 following [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x). Once a user has registered themselves, there appears to be no mechanism for them to delete their account.  The `AccountController.cs` file contains no mention of delete.

A user should be able to delete their account not least because of the [GDPR](https://www.eugdpr.org/) but deletion may be subject to constraints e.g. they have purchase records that have to be kept for a number of years for legal reasons. So what's the best way to implement user self-delete?

Comment: ASP.NET Core Identity 2.1 has a built-in form allowing a user to download their personal data or delete their account entirely, so that's what you should be looking at for new projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a security specialist so I'll be interested to see what's made of my solution. In ASP.NET Core 2.1 the template will include a self-delete option to conform with GDPR requirements. This will almost certainly be better than the following.

The tack I took was to require the user to enter their password again when deleting their account.

First create a ViewModel in the `Models/ManageViewModels` folder:

```
public class UserSelfDeleteViewModel
{
    [Editable(false)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Editable(false)]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The `[Editable(false)]` is not actually required but it makes it easier to understand when reviewing code months later.

To the `ManageController.cs` file add two actions:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> UserSelfDelete()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
    }

    // Validate business rules to ensure self-deletion is allowed, though it would
    // be a good idea to tell the user why their account cannot be deleted
    var userSelfDelete = new UserSelfDeleteViewModel
    {
        Email = user.Email,
        UserName = user.UserName
    };

    return View(userSelfDelete);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> UserSelfDelete(UserSelfDeleteViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
    }

    if (await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password) == false)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "Incorrect password entered");
        return View(model);
    }

    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged out prior to account deletion.");

    await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
}
```

This now needs a view in the `Manage` folder. I wanted to display the email address and user name, but have made them read-only:

```
@model UserSelfDeleteViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Delete this account";
}

<h4>@ViewData["Title"]</h4>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserName"></label>
                <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password"></label>
                 <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" autofill=""/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Delete your account</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial")
}
```

Now the navigation needs sorting out. To the `ManageNavPages.cs` file add the following lines:

```
public static string UserSelfDelete => "UserSelfDelete";
public static string UserSelfDeleteClass(ViewContext viewContext) => PageNavClass(viewContext, UserSelfDelete);
```

and finally add a link in `_ManageNav.cshtml` with the following:

```
<li class="@ManageNavPages.UserSelfDeleteClass(ViewContext)"><a asp-action="UserSelfDelete">Delete this account</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly for the reasons you indicate, most websites don't actually let users self-delete. Even when they have a way to "delete" or "remove" your account, what's actually happening is that it's a *request* to delete or remove the account. That means there's either a live human intervention or some automated process that takes care of it in a process-approved way.

In other words, you don't let a user literally issue a DELETE query against their user record. You process their request later, ensuring to archive or otherwise preserve any necessary records before actually removing anything from the database.

Comment: That's the way I used to do things: nothing was ever deleted immediately, but my feeling is that the GDPR has changed that. Since I made the post the ASP.NET Core  2.1 roadmap has been released and under 'Improvements for GDPR' it states that the templates will include 'a UI to allow users to download their personal data, along with the ability to delete their account entirely'.  I've worked out an interim solution that I will post in due course.